# How do I connect to database from admin?

Tags: admin, database

I created a custom table in the database called "referrals" where I store generated referral codes and link them from user to user. Upon registration, it adds the data just fine and when you log in, it displays just fine as well.

However, when logged in as the admin, I wanted to be able to view all of them, but for some reason I can't get any data to return. I even copied and pasted the block of code that is currently working.

This is what I'm using on the customers dashboard page and it works:

```
$email = $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getEmail());
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXXXX","XXXXX","XXXXX");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM referrals WHERE email='$email'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['referral_code'];
```

But when I copy it over to the admin side, it doesn't do anything. No errors or anything either.

It's located in a simple admin model that I found here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module

Does anybody have any idea why it's not returning any data at all?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do direct sql query as per zend framework. 
You will find some help from following links

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

http://www.vortexcommerce.com/blog/magento-direct-sql/

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I guess I just wasn't using the right search terms.